# Adafruit Feather Huzzah ESP8266 pull-up resistor using Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-ide, adafruit

I am working on the Adafruit Feather Huzzah ESP8266 and I would like to add an internal pull-up to a push button. When I do the pull-up manually with a resistor, my wiring works perfectly but when I add an internal pull-up using the following line in my Arduino IDE code, it does not work properly.

```cpp
pinMode(BOUTON,INPUT_PULLUP)
```

Here is my full code:

```cpp
const int LED = 13; 
const int BOUTON = 16; 

void setup() 
{
    pinMode(LED, OUTPUT); 
    pinMode(BOUTON, INPUT);
}

void loop()
{
    int etat = digitalRead(BOUTON);
    if(etat==LOW)
    {
        digitalWrite(LED, HIGH); 
    }
    else  
    {
        digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
    }
}
```

Here is my wiring with the pull-up:
[image]

Here is my wiring with supposed internal pull-up:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried already some other pins?

Comment: I had tried another pin for the LED but not for the switch and now it works...
Thank you ! Do you have any idea of the reason it could be ? The problem is on pin 16 which is a GPIO also...

Answer (score 3):

When writing a program, you had erroneously assumed that GPIO16 had a pullup resistor. It does not.

> At startup, pins are configured as INPUT.
>
> GPIO0-GPIO15 can be INPUT, OUTPUT, or INPUT_PULLUP. GPIO16 can be INPUT, OUTPUT, or INPUT_PULLDOWN_16. It is also XPD for deepSleep() (perhaps via a small capacitor.)
>
> Note that GPIO6-GPIO11 are typically used to interface
>   with the flash memory ICs on most esp8266 modules, so these pins
>   should not generally be used.

Reference: http://www.esp8266.com/wiki/doku.php?id=esp8266_gpio_pin_allocations

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Adafruits overview of the Feather HUZZAH ESP8266](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-feather-huzzah-esp8266?view=all). You are able to use the GPIO's 0, 2, 4, 5, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 but:

> These pins are general purpose and can be used for any sort of input
>   or output. **Most also have the ability to turn on an internal pullup**.
>   Many have special functionality.

Having detailed look at GPIO 16 shows us it is very special. The GPIO is used to wake up the controller from deep sleep. Therefore it is the only GPIO have a built in pull down resistor which is described in [this beginners guide](https://tttapa.github.io/ESP8266/Chap04%20-%20Microcontroller.html). This allows to directly connect with RESET. This means **GPIO 16 has no pull up resistor** like assumed.